# Does the Rust standard library have a Min/Max trait?

Tags: rust

I want to initialize a variable of type `T` with its minimum value like `T::min()`. Is it possible in Rust 1.40.0 without needing an external dependency?

An alternative approach is to set the variable to be `None`, but this introduces an overhead of `None` checking each time I want to increment the variable.

Comment: "An alternative approach is to setting the variable to be None. But this introduces an overhead of None checking each time I want to increment the variable." where does come from ?

Comment: do you mean something like [std::i32::MIN](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/i32/constant.MIN.html) or [std::i32::MAX](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/i32/constant.MAX.html)?

Comment: @khuynh yes but I'm inside a function that takes `T` as a parameter. Which means I don't know if `T ` is whether `i32` or `i8`. All I can do is to call the `min_value()` or `min()` to get the minimum.

Comment: Is this question an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? There may be a solution to your issue that doesn't require needing to know the min or max values of T.

Comment: Yes, as I said in the question, I can use optional types. However that introduces an overhead of checking if the variable is `None` or not before mutating it in a loop.

Comment: Note that wanting to use Rust without external dependencies is an exercise in frustration and needless self-limitation. Because Cargo works as well as it does, Rust's standard library is deliberately understuffed, and even basic things like random number generation are in external dependencies, sometimes maintained by the same people that maintain the standard library. If you're super afraid of supply chain attacks, you can specify the exact version of a crate in `Cargo.toml`, and if internet access is a problem, you can use `cargo vendor`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no such traits in the standard library.

However, it is possible to have a generic concept of min and max for arbitrary types without external dependencies if you are willing to create appropriate traits and implement them for the types you are interested in, for example:

```
use core::fmt::Display;

trait Min {
    fn min() -> Self;
}

trait Max {
    fn max() -> Self;
}

impl Min for u8 {
    fn min() -> u8 {
        std::u8::MIN
    }
}

impl Max for u8 {
    fn max() -> u8 {
        std::u8::MAX
    }
}

impl Min for i32 {
    fn min() -> i32 {
        std::i32::MIN
    }
}

impl Max for i32 {
    fn max() -> i32 {
        std::i32::MAX
    }
}

fn print_min_max<T: Min + Max + Display>() {
    println!("{} -> {}", T::min(), T::max());
}

fn main() {
    let m: i32 = Min::min();
    println!("{}", m);

    print_min_max::<u8>();
    print_min_max::<i32>();
}
```

This prints:

```
-2147483648
0 -> 255
-2147483648 -> 2147483647
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95d4930f80281eccc16d59aee945ac66)

Comment: This answer would be improved by directly answering the question: **no**, there is nothing like this in the standard library.

Comment: The traits Min and Max should probably depend on `Ord`.; it doesn't make much sense to have a highest and lowest element sans a total order.

Comment: @zorf consider points on the unit sphere ordered by z. There is a "maximum" and "minimum" element. And we can define an ordering of elements. But the ordering is not strictly a partial or total order. (since the property of assymetry is not satisfied.)

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I think you're mistaken; that *is* a totally ordered set. However, I agree that a total order is not necessary for a unique minimum or maximum value.

Comment: @trentcl Being a total order requires the "antisymmetry" property to hold i.e. "If a ≤ b and b ≤ a then a = b". But I might not want to consider points at the same height as actually being the same point. I might be surprised if I booked a flight to Miami and ended up in Taipei (Both at latitude 25 degree N).

Comment: @MichaelAnderson You are right; it is a total *pre*order when `=` is defined as caring about `x` and `y` but `<=` only cares about `z`. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

A solution in modern Rust could be define the trait as follows:

```
trait MyTrait {
     const MIN: Self;
}

impl MyTrait for u8 {
    const MIN: u8 = 42u8;
}

fn print_min<T: MyTrait + Display>() {
   println!("Value is {}", T::MIN);
}

print_min::<u8>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d2088e0b3b9bed4c01980e9b10713bb)

Comment: I'd love for this to be a thing. Unfortunately, I'm getting the expected error: `the trait bound 'u8: HasMin' is not satisfied; the trait 'HasMin' is not implemented for 'u8'`. Which is stupid because `u8::MIN` is definitely a thing. This on cargo 1.68 nightly

Comment: @MikolajFigurski This is a thing. Did you actually `impl HasMin for u8`?

Answer (score 1):

The question says "without external dependencies", so for completeness reasons only:

```rust
use num::traits::bounds::Bounded;

pub fn print_min<T: Bounded + std::fmt::Display>() {
    println!("minimum: {}", T::min_value());
}

print_min::<u8>();
```

(You could of course copy the [trait](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.15/src/num_traits/bounds.rs.html#8-15) and [implementation](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.15/src/num_traits/bounds.rs.html#43-65) to your own project since it's rather trivial.)